# How to run python from openCV (built from source) on the NVIDIA Jetson TX2?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, cmake, nvidia

I downloaded openCV from github and built it from source because I need a very specific release from openCV ie openCV2.4 .
When trying to run some code written in Python, I get "No module named cv2".

I therefor tried `pip install python-opencv`.
But this returns `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from version: ) No match distribution for opencv-python`

What can I do to solve the "No module named cv2" issue?

I also tried this straight in the command line

```
$python
>>>>import cv2
```

which returns no module named cv2 and

```
$python3
>>>>import cv2
```

which returns no module named cv2 as well.

I am however totally able to compile my C++ code. Which means the installation was somehow successful, but something fails on the Python side.

related to my issue: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/809406/jetson-tk1-opencv-python-quot-import-cv2-quot-/?offset=4#5207884

and

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1023652/jetson-tx2/how-can-i-run-quot-pip-install-opencv-python-quot-/?offset=5#5207902

**EDIT:**

I was suggested to run cmake with this flag set `-DBUILD_opencv_python2=ON`, but this flag doesn't seem to exist because when using cmake-gui I couldn't see it anywehere and when passing it in the terminal as a paramerer I get `Manually specified variables were not used by the project: BUILD_opencv_python`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install OpenCV 3.4.1 for python on the Jetson TX2 with Jetpack 3.1 with the directions [here](https://jkjung-avt.github.io/opencv3-on-tx2/).